# How do I make these string substitutions using hash keys in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of JSON files, processed in both Python and Ruby, that look something like this:

```
{
    "KEY1": "foo",
    "KEY2": "bar",

    "URL": "https://{KEY2}.com/{KEY1}",
    "IMPORTANT_THING": "repos/{KEY1}",
    "NOTE": "This thing is {KEY1}{KEY2}ed",
    "PYTHON_ONLY_THING": "{}/test/{}.py"
}
```

Note that the order that the keys will show up is not consistent, and I'd rather not change the JSON.

Here's my test code showing what I've tried so far:

```
my_config = {"KEY1"=>"foo",
             "KEY2"=>"bar",
             "URL"=>"https://{KEY2}.com/{KEY1}",
             "IMPORTANT_THING"=>"repos/{KEY1}",
             "NOTE"=>"This thing is {KEY1}{KEY2}ed",
             "PYTHON_ONLY_THING"=>"{}/test/{}.py"}

my_config.each_key do |key|
    # Braindead, hard-coded solution that works:
    # my_config[key].gsub!("{KEY1}", my_config["KEY1"])
    # my_config[key].gsub!("{KEY2}", my_config["KEY2"])

    # More flexible (if it would work):
    # my_config[key].gsub!(/{.*}/, my_config['\0'.slice(1,-2)])
    my_config[key].gsub!(/{.*}/) {|s| my_config[s.slice(1,-2)]}
end

puts my_config
```

I'm using the braindead solution for now, which produces the expected output:

```
{"KEY1"=>"foo", "KEY2"=>"bar", "URL"=>"https://bar.com/foo", "IMPORTANT_THING"=>"repos/foo", "NOTE"=>"This thing is foobared", "PYTHON_ONLY_THING"=>"{}/test/{}.py"}
```

But I want to make it more flexible and maintainable.  The first "better" solution throws an error apparently because slice operates on '\0' itself and not the match, plus I'm not sure it would match more than once.  The currently uncommented solution doesn't work because the second part seems to operate on one letter at a time rather than each match like I expected, so it just removes the stuff in curly braces.  Worse, it removes everything between the outer braces in the PYTHON_ONLY_THING, which is no good.

I figure I need to change both my regex and Ruby code if this is going to work, but I'm not sure where to look for more help.  Or perhaps gsub isn't the right tool for this job.  Any ideas?

I am using Ruby 2.3.7 on Linux x86_64.

Comment: The second param for `slice` is length. Won't it always return a `nil` if its a negative integer?

Comment: That is not valid JSON

Comment: @Sinstein Ah, good catch!  I misread the docs.  Obviously I am very much a beginner in Ruby. :)

Comment: @engineersmnky Fixed.  I made that up on the spot and it's not used so it's not terribly important. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) with an initial hash for replacements:

```
my_config.map do |k, v|
  [
    k,
    v.gsub(/(?<={)[^}]+(?=})/, my_config).gsub(/{(?!})|(?<!{)}/, '')
  ]
end.to_h
#⇒ {"KEY1"=>"foo",
#   "KEY2"=>"bar",
#   "URL"=>"https://bar.com/foo",
#   "IMPORTANT_THING"=>"repos/foo",
#   "NOTE"=>"This thing is foobared",
#   "PYTHON_ONLY_THING"=>"{}/test/{}.py"}
```

Starting with Ruby 2.4 (or using Rails) it might be done simpler using `Hash#transform_values`.

If you dislike the second gsubbing, transform the hash upfront:

```
my_substs = my_config.map { |k, v| ["{#{k}}", v] }.to_h
my_config.map do |k, v|
  [k, v.gsub(/{[^}]+}/, my_substs)]
end.to_h
```

Comment: I like the second answer best! (But as OP mentioned ruby 2.3, they may not be able to fully utilise that, as you said)

Comment: Very nice!  I prefer the method of transforming the hash to pass to gsub.  I have a question, though.  For this to work with my code I made the map block `my_config=my_config.map...(snip)...end.to_h`.  Is that what you would expect?  It looks a bit messy.  Is making a copy via map preferable to or more common than using each_key and then gsub! for in-place modification (like I did before)? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, `to_h` was intended, sorry.

Comment: Actually, the equivalent of `Hash#transform_values` has been around for a long time: `h.merge(h) { |_,value,_| ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution:

```
my_config = {"KEY1"=>"foo",
             "KEY2"=>"bar",
             "URL"=>"https://{KEY2}.com/{KEY1}",
             "IMPORTANT_THING"=>"repos/{KEY1}",
             "NOTE"=>"This thing is {KEY1}{KEY2}ed",
             "PYTHON_ONLY_THING"=>"{}/test/{}.py"}

my_config.each_key do |key|
  placeholders = my_config[key].scan(/{([^}]+)}/).flatten
  placeholders.each do |placeholder|
    my_config[key].gsub!("{#{placeholder}}", my_config[placeholder]) if my_config.keys.include?(placeholder)
  end
end

puts my_config
```

- By using `scan`, this will substitute all matches, not just the first match.
- Using `[[^}]+` in the regex, rather than `.*`, means you won't "swallow" too much in this part of the match. For example, if the input contains `"{FOO} bar {BAZ}"`, then you want that pattern to only capture `FOO` and `BAZ`, not `FOO} bar {BAZ`.
- Grouping the scan result, then calling `flatten`, is an easy way to reject what's outside the capture group, i.e. in this case the `{` and `}` characters. (This just makes the code a little less cryptic than using indexes like `slice(1,-2)`!
- `my_config.keys.include?(placeholder)` checks whether this is actually . a known value, so you don't replace things with `nil`.

Comment: [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts a hash as replacements :)

Comment: Yeah, true... But this method has a slightly less confusing regex :)

Comment: It's also a lot slower since this requires doing N*M passes on the string instead of just N.

Comment: Thank you!  I greatly appreciate the thorough explanations and the additional error checking.  I understood it very quickly and it worked on my test code as-is.